# Does Infragistics supports Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, binding, infragistics

Since it is way too easy creating a binding between a DataSets and the DataSource property of the windows form objects I was expecting the same behavior, or similar using EF Context Objects. In Theory it should be this way because it's a newer tech, but in the practice they doesn't get along very well. In fact 1-1 relationships doesn't even appear in design. 
Plundering the internet I recently found a very peculiar article solving the problem for 1-* relationships by modifying the t4 template auto-generated by the .edmx model. However, even when it seems to work, it's a very bad solution due to 1-1 relationships and the invasive changes to the t4 template.

To sum up:

Is it possible to create a full Master-Details UltraGrid using an EF object as Datasource and the grid could navigate through their properties automatically creating child bands (including 1-1 relationships)?

Comment: The first paragraph is totally irrelevant/vague to me. And the second doesn't sum it up. In fact, you could remove the first paragraph and still have a question. Still vague though. It begs for an example + code.

Comment: i dont have the code example, because it is in design mode of the control, I can't bind in design mode and ultragrid to a EF context object.